# incompatible types: T#1 cannot be converted to T#2

Tags: java, generics, gson

I am going to create one generic class, first i want to say my requirement. I have different classes e.g. A,B etc. I am going to create an instance of class based on the json object. This json object will be read from file. The file may contain equivalent json object.based on it i will create an instance of that class using GSON. Now i face one error i.e. `incompatible types: T#1 cannot be converted to T#2`

This is my code sample

```
public class JsonLoader<T> {

    private final  Gson gson = new Gson();

    private final T content;

    public <T> JsonLoader(Class<T> clazz, String filePath) throws IllegalFileException {
        if (filePath.isEmpty() || filePath == null) {
            throw new IllegalFileException("IllegalFileException: source file must required.");
        }
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader(filePath)) {
            T content= gson.fromJson(reader, clazz);
            this.content = content;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalFileException(e.getMessage(),e);
        }

    }

    public <T> T getObject() {
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post more information about the error? Line number?

Comment: @Kevinrob `incompatible types: inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: T#2
    upper bounds: T#3,Object
  where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>fromJson(Reader,Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in constructor <T#2>JsonLoader(Class<T#2>,String)
    T#3 extends Object declared in class JsonLoader`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare the type parameter `T` on the class, the entire class body has access to that type parameter, so you don't need to redeclare it. When you say `public <T> JsonLoader` and `public <T> T getObject` you are actually declaring new type parameters with the same name which shadow the type parameter on the class.

This is similar to how you can declare a variable which shadows a field:

```
class Example {
    int foo;
    // parameter foo shadows the field foo
    Example(int foo) {}
}
```

If you remove the type parameter declarations on the constructor and method it should just work.